# Upgrading from jQuery 1.5 to 1.7

Tags: jquery

What all are the things to take care of when upgarding from 1.5.1 to 1.7 ?

I am using the following plugins will they break/conflict if I upgrade.

1. jQuert UI
2. Validate
3. Cycle

Comment: Go ahead and try it... though it does not seem that 1.7 is released yet.

Comment: @FelixKling I assume he's talking about the beta. http://blog.jquery.com/2011/10/13/jquery-1-7-beta-2-released/

Comment: @Nick: Yes, just followed your link... thanks!

Comment: Install it.  If things break, just put back 1.5.1... what else can anyone here really tell you?

Comment: i basically wanted to know if anyone tried it and face any issues with it

Comment: Test it... let us know if you have any issues with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [change log](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/10/13/jquery-1-7-beta-2-released/) to see if anything drastic has happened.  In general, it should work the same.  The best way to see if your plugins will work is to try it!

If you're really worried, check out the homepages of each of the plugins to see if they have detected any issues.

Normally, new versions will only increase compatibility so if anything you should have *fewer* problems.  However, be weary of upgrading to a beta version as this may well have bugs that will be ironed out before the official release.